# How i can call controller function from view?

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am fetching all details of product from database, and successfully get in view, but in between there is product details is too long so i want to split that text. I have also create a function of limit_text in main controller that is:

```
function limit_text($text, $length) // Limit Text
{
    if(strlen($text) > $length) {
        $stringCut = substr($text, 0, $length);
        $text = substr($stringCut, 0, strrpos($stringCut, ' '));
    }
    return $text;
}
```

but problem is that i unable to call this function from view....please help me..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of creating function in your controller, i suggest you create it in [helper](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/helpers.html) so that you can access it easily from view file.
Create helper, say **mysome_helper.php**:

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

function limit_text($text, $length) // Limit Text
{
    if(strlen($text) > $length) {
        $stringCut = substr($text, 0, $length);
        $text = substr($stringCut, 0, strrpos($stringCut, ' '));
    }
    return $text;
}
```

and load it in your controller:

```
$this->load->helper('mysome');
```

and then you can access in view, like:

```
<?php echo limit_text("some long tezxt", 120); ?>
```

Comment: @user3415023 you're welcome.. :) Btw, try reading thru the docs to get a better understanding before you start coding..

Answer (score 0):

you don't - use a Helper function